# Maximum Length of a Triangle

Tags: calculus, triangles, maxima-minima

I am stuck on a question concerning right triangles. I will list my approach out below:

**Question**

Consider a right-angled triangle with hypothenuse (i.e. diagonal side) of length 2 and draw a vertical line from the midpoint of the hypothenuse to the corresponding cathetus (i.e. the bottom side). You should get a picture as drawn below. What is the maximal total length of all lines (including the hypothenuse)?

[image]

**Reasoning**

Comment: You forgot to post the reasoning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the legs of the larger triangle are $2a$ and $2b.$

Our objective is $L = 2a + 3b + 2$

Constrained by $a^2 + b^2 = 1$

Now the way that I like to do these is to take the derivative of both functions, setting the derivative of the objective function equal to $0.$  This is not the way it is usually taught.

$2\ da  + 3 \ db = 0\\
2a\ da + 2b \ db = 0$

Substituting from one equation into the other.

$(-3a + 2b) db = 0$

$db$ may be very small but it is not zero.

$2b = 3a$

And substitute this into the constraint.

$a^2 + (\frac {3a}{2})^2 = 1\\
\frac {13}{4} a^2 = 1\\
a = \sqrt {\frac {4}{13}}\\
b = \sqrt {\frac {9}{13}}\\
L = \frac {13}{\sqrt {13}} + 2 = \frac {\sqrt {13}}{13} + 2$

The more conventional thing to do is to substitute based on the constraint before differentiating.

$a^2 + b^2 = 1\\
a  = \sqrt {1-b^2}\\
L = 2\sqrt {1-b^2} + 3 b$

Differentiate, set the derivative equal to $0$ and solve for $b.$

However, after working this out, I see a 3rd possibility.  We can say
$a = \cos \theta\\
b = \sin\theta\\
L = 2\cos\theta + 3\sin\theta + 2$

Now there is no constraint to deal with.
$-2\sin\theta + 3\cos\theta = 0\\
\theta = \arctan \frac {3}{2}$